# Django save user profile manually

Tags: python, django

I have created a `Profile` and attached to user model using `OneToOneField`. I have a registration form where user enters input which corresponds to user and profile. Django provides `User.objects.create_user` to save fields which are related to `User` model, but i don't know how to save details of `Profile` model manually.
Here is my code:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, required=True)
    # lot more fields here
```

**views.py**

```
@csrf_protect
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        full_name = request.POST.get('full_name', '')
        username = request.POST.get('username', '')
        password = request.POST.get('password', '')
        User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
        # how to save Profile full_name here

    return render(request, 'register.html')
```

**register.html**

```
<form method="post" action="/register/">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="full_name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="full_name" id="full_name">
    </div>  
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username">
    </div>
    <div class="form">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="pass" name="password" value="" id="password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**1)** How can i save `full_name` of `Profile` model in `views.py` ? Can I do this without creating form class for every model in the future that want to save or Signals?
**2)** Do I need to change `auth_user_model` in settings.py in order to save profile details manually?
**3)** How to validate the fields without creating a new Form class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@csrf_protect
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        full_name = request.POST.get('full_name', '')
        username = request.POST.get('username', '')
        password = request.POST.get('password', '')
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
        Profile.objects.create(user=user,full_name=full_name)
        # how to save Profile full_name here

    return render(request, 'register.html')
```

you can use the created user instance to create the profile associated with that user

Comment: when i use `python manage.py makemigrations` i am getting `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'required'`

Comment: remove the required=True from the full_name of your profile model

Comment: but i need full_name every time

Comment: yes, keeping full_name = models.CharField(max_length=150) only will make it required

Comment: did you get it @nivas

Comment: thanks it resolved, sorry this is the first time i ran migrate i got `MySQL Strict Mode is not set for database connection 'default'` this warning

Comment: 'OPTIONS': {
        'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'",
    },

add this line after the last line inside the default database in the settings.py

Comment: do i need to delete all tables and migrations, start from scratch? otherwise just run migration again or no migration just use it

Comment: you can or you dont have too, it wont effect too much

Comment: Thanks for all your help... if i have any issue i will contact

Comment: sure, will be glad to help you, and do mention my name here only, will try to help as much as possible